# verilog doesn't see my function

Tags: module, compiler-errors, verilog, alu

```
    module fa(a,b,cin,cout,sum);
        input a;
        input b;
        wire bxor;
        input cin;
        output cout;
        output sum;

        assign  bxor = b ^ cin;
        assign  sum  = ((a^bxor)^(cin));
        assign  cout = ((a&bxor)|((a^bxor)&cin));
endmodule

module rca(a,b,cin,cout,sum);
        input cin;
        output cout;
        output [7:0] sum;
        input [7:0] a, b;
        wire c[6:0];     

        fa first(a[0],b[0],cin,c[0],sum[0]);
        fa second(a[1],b[1],c[0],c[1],sum[1]);
        fa third(a[2],b[2],c[1],c[2],sum[2]);
        fa fourth(a[3],b[3],c[2],c[3],sum[3]);
        fa fifth(a[4],b[4],c[3],c[4],sum[4]);
        fa sixth(a[5],b[5],c[4],c[5],sum[5]);
        fa seventh(a[6],b[6],c[5],c[6],sum[6]);
        fa eighth(a[7],b[7],c[6],cout,sum[7]);
endmodule

module alu_op(a,b,op,out);
        input [7:0] a, b;
        input [2:0] op;
        output [7:0] out;
        output reg out1;

        always @ (op or a or b)
                case (op)
                        3'b000 : out1 = fa(a, b, op[0], op[0], out);
                        3'b001 : out1 = fa(a,b,op[0], op[0], out);
                        //3'b010 : out = shift shifter (a[7:0],b[7:0],out[7:0]);
                        3'b011 : out1 = a ^ b;
                        3'b100 : out1 = a | b;
                        3'b101 : out1 = a & b;
                endcase
endmodule
```

I'm thinking it's because you can't call a function in a case statement. I'm completely new to this and have no idea what to do. I'm basically making an alu and the first two cases is supposed to do add and sub.

when i compile I get:

```
alutester.vl:66: error: No function fa in this context (alu.utt).
alutester.vl:67: error: No function rca in this context (alu.utt).
```

i have no idea why. can someone help me please?

Comment: I tried to use the ripple carry adder I have there but I couldn't figure out how so i just used the full adder. If the rca would be better let me know please

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a *function* called `fa`, you created a *module* called `fa` (they are not the same thing). And you can't instantiate modules inside procedural blocks.

It's also not clear what you're trying to do with those modules. I'm not sure what this means

`out1 = fa(a, b, op[0], op[0], out);`

First of all, you're tying op[0] to both cin and cout, which seems wrong, and it's not clear what value `out1` is supposed to take. Is it supposed to get the sum output of the adder? If you want to take out1 from some output of the fa, then instantiate it outside the always block, and set out1 equal to the wire coming from the module in the case that you want.

Comment: op[0] chooses the first bit of the operation you want to do. 0 or 1. if it's 0 it will add and subtract if it is 1. out1 is supposed to be the output of the alu.

Comment: In that case, you need to disconnect op[0] from `cout`, as that will give you wire contention on that signal and force it to 'x'. Instantiate your ALU's outside of a procedural block, assign the alu's output to a wire, and then tie that wire to out1 in the case you want to sample from the ALU's output

Answer (score 1):

Let's see... you have built an 8-bit adder, the `rca` module.

Later on, you have what seems to be an ALU that takes `a` and `b` as input operands, and assign `out1` depending upon the operation that is willing to be performed.

Either you instantiate the `rca` module in your `alu_op` module in order to have available the sum of `a` plus `b`,...

```
module alu_op(a,b,op,out);
        input [7:0] a, b;
        input [2:0] op;
        output [7:0] out;
        output reg out1;

        wire [7:0] sum;
        rca my_adder(.a(a),.b(b),.cin(1'b0),.sum(sum))

        always @ (op or a or b)
                case (op)
                        3'b000 : out1 = sum;
                        //3'b010 : out = shift shifter (a[7:0],b[7:0],out[7:0]);
                        3'b011 : out1 = a ^ b;
                        3'b100 : out1 = a | b;
                        3'b101 : out1 = a & b;
                endcase
endmodule
```

Or (surely better), let the compiler just figure out how to build an adder, by using the `+` operator.

```
module alu_op(a,b,op,out);
        input [7:0] a, b;
        input [2:0] op;
        output [7:0] out;
        output reg out1;

        always @ (op or a or b)
                case (op)
                        3'b000 : out1 = a + b;
                        //3'b010 : out = shift shifter (a[7:0],b[7:0],out[7:0]);
                        3'b011 : out1 = a ^ b;
                        3'b100 : out1 = a | b;
                        3'b101 : out1 = a & b;
                endcase
endmodule
```

BTW: bit shifting is also a valid Verilog operand, and, as I'm pretty sure you want substraction (for operation 001), the minus `-` operator is available as well. Addition, bit shitting and substraction are synthetizable as well.